# Loading Webview in Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, webview

I'm loading a Mastercard payment gateway as such, I pass the initial file, which is an HTML file that generates a session ID. When that's generated, It should append the session ID to the current window and load that page which prouduces the form for the user to make payment. However for some reason, this doesn't load the form, it remains stuck on the initial file that was loaded. This works fine on Android and iOS, but not on Web. What could be the problem?

This is my implementation below:

````
              key: webViewKey,
              initialFile: FileConstant.paymentPage,
              // initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
              //     url: WebUri(
              //         "http://localhost:12345/checkout.html",
              //         forceToStringRawValue: true)),
              initialSettings: settings,
              onWebViewCreated: (controller) async {
                setState(() {
                  webViewController = controller;
                });
                webViewController = controller;
                 await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
                  controller.evaluateJavascript(
                      source:
                          "window.location = window.location.href+'?session=${widget.data['SESSION']}';");
                          print("window.location = window.location.href+'?session=${widget.data['SESSION']}';");
                });
              },
              onLoadStart: (controller, url) async {
                print('load started');
              },
              onPermissionRequest: (controller, request) async {
                return PermissionResponse(
                    resources: request.resources,
                    action: PermissionResponseAction.GRANT);
              },
              onLoadStop: (controller, url) async {
                print('onLoadStop: $url');
                myUrl = url!;
              },
              onLoadError: (controller, url, code, message) {
                print('error occurred onLoadError');
                webViewKey = GlobalKey();
                _setState();
              },
              onProgressChanged: (controller, progress) {
                if (progress == 100) {}
                this.progress = progress / 100;
                _setState();
              },
              onUpdateVisitedHistory: (controller, url, androidIsReload) {
                _setState();
              },
              onConsoleMessage: (controller, consoleMessage) =>
                  handleMessage(consoleMessage)),```
````